# Compiling .tex files seem to be tied to a username?

Tags: latex, buffers, auctex

I'm working on multiple computers and compiling LaTeX document through AUCTeX. I've set up Evince as my external viewer and the synctex and back referencing work perfectly...

...as long as I've compiled the .tex file on the same computer. See, I have different Linux usernames on the different computers, and somehow it seems that the compilation is tied to the username. If I am on Computer 1, with user1 account, trying to use the synctex generated on Computer 2 with user2, it will open an empty buffer named `latex.tex<user2>`.

I have no idea how to solve this issue, and I couldn't find any setting (on AUCTeX or otherwise) that would fix this, nor I found any shred of mention of a username in the synctex.gz file data. Any suggestions?

(Yes, I do have an \author{} field, and no, it is not either of the user1 or user2.)

Comment: @db48x I think you don't understand my question.

Comment: I think it's more likely to have something to do with your *compiler* which may record `$USER` in the target file.

Comment: @Shynur: But I can't find anything like that in the pdf either, and surely there should be a way to make emacs ignore that?

Comment: Whether *user1* and *user2* exist on the same machine at the same time? Are there directories named `user1` and `user2` on this machine?

Comment: @shynur: No, these are two separate machines. One is a user given to me by my workplace and the other is my user account on my private computer.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer name is by default taken from the name of the file being edited, but it is not that uncommon to edit multiple files with the same name (naturally these files must all be in different directories). Emacs must create a unique buffer name even when the file names are different, and there are several ways that it can do so. Some of them involve extending the buffer name using part of the path as well.

See chapter [19.7.1 Making Buffer Names Unique](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html) in the Emacs manual for more details.

Comment: But that's what I mean. If I open the .tex file and the .pdf file, and I click to back reference, it will instead open a blank buffer named `file.tex<user2>`. If I recompile the tex file, it just works.

Comment: Is the blank buffer visiting a file? If so, what is the path to that file?

Comment: It claims to visit the "file.tex<user2>"